# I make select from DB, but it returns empty values

Tags: php

I have PDO select, it seems to work when i test in sql but in reall it doesnot work.

```
$sql= $this->db->prepare("SELECT  title,  DATE(date) as dmy, short_description, description FROM  `news`  WHERE  newsID=".$newsID."");
                    $sql->execute();
```

I mean does not work that when I want to print any selected variable its empty. Thanks for help

Comment: You haven't shown any code that tries to print any results from your query.

Comment: This just runs the query, you need to get the result(s).  P.S. *Never* concatenate a variable into an SQL query.  Especially when you're using prepared statements.  `WHERE newsID=:newsid` then do `->execute(array(':newsid' => $newsID ));`.

Comment: date and DATE are both reserve words.if you have a column name as date then add the table name with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a prepared statement, you have to bind the where parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Did you not do a $sql->fetch();

```
for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
    echo $row['name'];
  }
```

something like that should work.
Right now it executes the query but your not fetching the result.

Comment: What's with the `$i` here?  The "normal" way to do this is just `while($row = $query->fetch()){}`.

Comment: ferch does not help :(

Comment: @RocketHazmat You are correct. I just copied a section from [here](http://www.php.net/pdo.query). There are a few ways of doing it although the for loop should also work. $i just acts like a counter in this case.

Comment: $sql= $this->db->prepare("SELECT  title,  DATE(date) as dmy, short_description, description FROM  `news`  WHERE  WHERE newsID=:newsid ");
     $sql->execute(array(':newsid' => $newsID ));
     while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      
     echo "aleluiaaa";
     }

Comment: I changed it so, but again I have problem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is that you need to wrap your value in single quotes.  Give this a go:

```
$sql= $this->db->prepare("SELECT  title,  DATE(date) as dmy, short_description, description FROM  `news`  WHERE  newsID='".$newsID."'");
$sql->execute();
```

If that doesn't work, try printing out any error message (from the database) about the last query you sent to see if that helps you narrow the problem.

Comment: No, integers should not be quoted in SQL. Only strings.

Comment: @Jessica Who said OP was dealing with an integer?  Does that really warrant a downvote??  Key values can be strings you know...

Comment: They can, but an ID should not be. It should be an integer. Plus, the OP apparently knows it's an int since he didn't quote it in the first place. :)

Comment: @Jessica From a design principal, yes integers are preferred (I know I use them) but they can be strings, I've used them that way too.  Strings vs. ints wasn't the point I was making.  The point I was making is that you downvoted me over single quotes over an *assumption* OP was using an int. If OP said they were using an int, would be a different story (and my bad...).  I felt it was unnecessary and misuse of a downvote.

Comment: Your answer also didn't address the fact that the OP isn't even running the query. There are multiple issues with the OP's code that are not related to quoting a string. Sorry you don't like that I didn't like your answer, but I don't find your answer to be correct in any way, and misleading in other ways. End.

Comment: Also, the last person who disagreed with me downvoting their comment decided to stalk me and downvote all of my posts. If you do that, you are a child. Accept it and move on.

Comment: @Jessica It is hindsight at this point and not worth the argument. Nobody is prefect, if there was multiple things wrong with my answer, be objective and point them out.  As for the stalking remark, the mere assumption I would do such a thing is ridiculous.  I have far better things to do with my time.  Rest assured I am not going to be trolling your answers.